# Strange error message in my perl program

Tags: perl

I have lines in the program:

```
  $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} = nearest(.000001, MOA::CLSUtils::get_price( $data->{external_mf}->{pool_cusip}  ,$start_date) );     
  $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} = ( defined ( $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} ) ) ? $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} : 0;     
  $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} ||=0;    
  $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} = nearest ( .01, $data->{external_mf}->{pre_price} ) if ( $&& $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/);
```

When I run the program, got an error:

> Use of uninitialized value $& in bitwise and (&) at
>   G:\invacct\perl\scripts\pfi_ general_ledger_check.pl line 286.

Line 286 is the last in segment above. Can anybody tell me what should it be?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this statement `if ( $&& $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/ ) { }`?

Comment: [`$&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is a valid variable in Perl and [`&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And) is the bitwise-and operator. This statement is probably not doing what you want/expect.

Comment: The problem is that I just got this program and trying to understand what it does and why it has so many errors.

Comment: What do you mean you got this program? From where? (Also, stackoverflow isn't application support.)

Comment: I think `$&& $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/` used to be `$<something> && $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/` and something was erased accidentally

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
... if ( $&& $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/)
```

which parses as

```
... if $& & $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/;
```

It's hard to tell what you meant by this, but `$&` holds the string last matched by a regex pattern. It is `undef` here, presumably because you haven't previously used regex patterns in your code

It looks like this may be enough. Note that you must also *anchor* your regex pattern, otherwise it will match any substring instead of the whole string

```
$data->{external_mf}{pre_price} = nearest(0.01, $data->{external_mf}{pre_price} )
        unless $args->{port} =~ /^200[12]6$/
```

---

It may help to see this code refactored properly. I would write it like this

```
$data->{external_mf}{pre_price} = do {

    my $price = MOA::CLSUtils::get_price($data->{external_mf}{pool_cusip}, $start_date);

    if ( $price ) {
        my $precision = $args->{port} =~ /^200[12]6$/) ? 0.000001 : 0.01;
        $price = nearest($precision, $price);
    }
    else {
        $price = 0;
    }

    $price;
};
```

Comment: It seems like $& not need to be used in this line. It doesn't mean anything because I don't see any regular expression before it.

Comment: @nelli: I agree with you. Even if it was a valid test it would look like `if $& && $args->{port} !~ /20016|20026/`. I think your predecessor was simply inept

Comment: coul,d you please tell me, how to print each of mtghe following variables:                                                                                           $data->{external_mf}->{cur_price} = nearest(.000001,  $data->{external_mf}->{cur_price} + $data->{external_mf}->{daily_div_rate}

Comment: @nelli: Just `print $data->{external_mf}->{cur_price}, "\n"` etc.

Comment: No, it show me Scalar found where operator expected

Comment: @nelli Have you missed the comma before the newline? Is there a semicolon missing from the previous line? Have you put a semicolon at the end of this line? Please show exactly what you have written, including the previous statement